# How to make Ninject return a mock object

Tags: linq, unit-testing, ninject, moq

I have a code that looks like this

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ContextWrapper contextWrapper;
    public EmployeeController (IContextWrapper wrapper) 
    { 
        contextWrapper = wrapper;
    }
```

In my dependency resolver I have the binding for IContextWrapper

```
kernel.Bind<IContextWrapper>().To<ContextWrapper>();
```

The implementation of ContextWrapper has an object which is of type Linq DataContext.

```
public class ContextWrapper : IContextWrapper
{
    public MyDataContext dataContext;

    public ContextWrapper(MyDataContext  context)
    {
        this.dataContext = context;
    }
```

Now my action method in this controller looks like this

```
var empRepository = new EmployeeRepository(contextWrapper);
//do some tests with this repository.
some values = contextWrapper.datacontext.get some values from the database table
//do some tests with these values.
```

To be able to test this method

1. I should be able to provide some sort of mock database(not literally) or
2. make the contextWrapper.datacontext return mocked values or
3. I even thought of creating another implementation of the IContextWrapper that doesn't use a Linq DataContext object. And creating another constructor for this controller and pass that fake implementation. Also in  my dependency resolver I would bind the fake object to the IContextWrapper. Although I do not know how to make Ninject
4. As a last resort test my method against a test database since it all boils down to this Linq DataContext object and it seems I cannot get rid of it past a certain level.

Problem is the more I read about it, more I get confused. I have tried to give as much detail as possible to explain my problem. If any one has a clear cut idea about how to get this, please suggest.

Comment: Why don't you inject repositories also via the constructor rather than creating them inside the controller? Then it would be much more easier

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican: Alright. I have also thought of that. That would solve the problems of EmployeeRepository. But what about the line where datacontext comes into picture?

Comment: You can either use another `.Bind<MyDataContext>()...` or `.Rebind<MyDataContext>()` in your test. You can do something like `.ToConstant(.. mocked instance)` so that you can setup the mock/fake from outside. However, testing db access this way is rather cumbersome. It is often times recommended that you do integration tests instead (p.Ex. using an in memory database which you set up with some data and then testing that "values" contains the expected data...)

Comment: The idea of adding a repository layer is not to refer it inside the higher layers, so to be able to test easily you should encapsulate all the direct access to Data Context in repositories, and then you can mock the repository and pass it to the constructor